# How to call a model's method before saving a serializer in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model where I am trying to create an object using DRF. The model class has a method which I would like to call before saving the serializer. Something like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    def do_something(self):
        ...
```

The serializer code:

```
serializer = MyModelSerializer(data=request.data)
serializer.obj.do_something() # Does not work
serializer.save()
```

Hopefully, you guys get the idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Afaik DRF doesn't support things such as `save(commit=False)` but, alternatively, you can override `MyModelSerializer.create` method:

```
class MyModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def create(self, validated_data):
        instance = MyModel(**validated_data)
        instance.do_something()
        instance.save()
        return instance
```